# Testable python class which depends on another class?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a class `C` which is used by `X`, for which I will write unit tests.

```
class C(metaclass=Singleton):  # To be mocked
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        """..."""
    def f(self, x):
        return ...

class X:  # to be tested
    def __init__(self, c: C=C(...)):  # do I need parameter c for testability?
        self.c = c

x = X()  # self.c will be ready
```

To keep the same testability, do I need constructor parameter `c: C=C(...)`? How about just

```
class X:  # to be tested
    def __init__(self):  # No parameter c
        self.c = C(...)

    def g(self):
        x = self.c.f(...)
```

And use some approaches to "patch" `C.f()`? How are the difference of test code looks? I will use pytest.

Comment: `c` is a param to your class, you can just pass a mock object

Comment: Pass whatever you like. Something named `Config` sounds like something you could easily construct for the test, no mocks or stubs needed.

Comment: I want to remove it from constructor parameter so the code is simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware, instantiating an object as default value for a parameter will share the same object between deifferent calls (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)).

As for your question, if you really to want the call to X the same, as in `x = X()  # self.c will be ready` then you will need to patch the `Config` reference that your `X.__init__` uses.
If you relax this constraint, meaning that you accept to do `x = X(c=Config())` instead, it will be very easy to provide the "[test double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_double)" of your choice (typically a "mock"), and ease testing. It is called [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and facilitating testing is one of its main advantages.

**EDIT**: as you need to mock `C.f`, here is an example :

```py
class C:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def f(self, z):  # <-- renamed to `z` to avoid confusion with the `x` instance of class `X`
        print(f"method F called with {z=}, {self.a=} and {self.b=}")
        return z + self.a + self.b


class X:
    def __init__(self, c: C = C(a=1, b=2)):
        self.c = c


# /!\ to do some mocking, I had to `pip install pytest_mock` (version 3.6.1) as `pytest` provides no mocking support
def test_my_class_X_with_C_mock(mocker):  # the `mocker` parameter is a fixture, it is automatically provided by the pytest runner
    x = X()  # create the X as always

    assert x.c.f(z=3) == 6  # prints "method F called with z=3, self.a=1 and self.b=2"

    def my_fake_function_f(z):  # create a function to call instead of the original `C.f` (optional)
        print(f"mock intercepted call, {z=}")
        return 99
    my_mock = mocker.Mock(  # define a mock
        **{"f.side_effect": my_fake_function_f})  # which has an `f`, which calls the fake function when called (side effect)
    mocker.patch.object(target=x, attribute="c", new=my_mock)  # patch : replace `x.c` with `my_mock` !

    assert x.c.f(z=3) == 99  # prints "mock intercepted call, z=3"


def main():
    # do the regular thing
    x = X()
    print(x.c.f(z=3))  # prints "method F called with z=3, self.a=1 and self.b=2" and the result "6"

    # then do the tests
    import pytest
    pytest.main(["-rP", __file__])  # run the test, similar to the shell command `pytest <filename.py>`, and with `-rP` show the print
    # it passes with no error !


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Because `C` already exists (it is in the same file) in your example, it was not possible to simply [`mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch), it was required to `mock.patch.object`.
Also, it is possible to write simpler mocks, or just let `patch` create a plain `Mock`, but for the example I preferred to be explicit.

Comment: Sorry, the question was updated. `Config` should be `C` in the question. I added a function `C.f()`. The test code will need to mock `C.f()`.

Comment: @ca9163d9 I updated my answer

Comment: @ca9163d9 if it answers your updated question, then don't forget to mark my answer as "accepted" ;-)

Comment: I actually want to test `X` instead of `C`. `C` should be a mock object. And I want to write the code without using constructor parameter (simpler?) if it doesn't affect any testability.

Comment: @ca9163d9 look at the example I wrote : `x.c` is mocked, so when you do something with `x` in your tests you are using the mock, not the actual `C` class. You can see that in the `test_my_class` function, in which the first assert uses the actual C (for example purpose) then mock it, and the second assert uses the mock. This way, you can test your `X` class being assured that no `C` method will get called.

Comment: @ca9163d9 if what you want is to completely mock away the `C` class, it is not possible in a simple way according to the example you wrote. Either you don't set a default value in `X.__init__` (and do **dependency injection**), either you can put `X` and `C` in different files, so that your test can `mock.patch` the `import C` from the `X` definition file, so that it uses a mock `C`class. The latter is less robust and less clear.

Comment: It's good just mock `C.f()`. Let it return a particular value given some parameters.

Comment: @ca9163d9 so did it solve your problem ? If so, mark the answer as "accepted" :)

Comment: It's marked as accepted a few days ago. Thanks.